# Invalid character in UTF-8 when geocoding in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geocoding, utf-8

I am using QGIS 2.18. As suggested, I installed the MMQGIS plugin to help me geocode the csv file containing a list of addresses. I converted the file to utf-8 encoding format. But when i was trying to import the file, it said my file contains invalid characters. I checked my file and could't spot any.

Comment: What is the path of the file ?

Comment: Use of UTF-8 *encoding* doesn't mean the data is UTF-8 *encoded*. You'd need to dump the string as hexadecimal from binary in order to locate the invalid data.